# understanding total effect when including a variable in different interactions in the same model

Tags: interaction

[image]

I use an OLS regression to verify if ( taking into account different interaction effects) being calssified as a MNE result in higher/lower ETR ( dependent variable) 
MNE= Dummy
LARGEDO= dummy
SME= dummy ( reference group)
ETR= dependent variable ( continuous)

What I want to know is how I can interpret the effect of being a MNE compared with an SME on the ETR ( taking into account the different interaction effects). Is that possible? or when I interpret one interaction with MNE included I have to interpret it " with the other interaction term constant"...
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `MNE` a binary regressor that represents `1`:`MNE` and `0`:`SME`, then what you want to do is take the first derivative of this function with respect to `MNE`.

This would leave you with `.027-.064EQRATIO-.062FINAR`.  That is the estimated effect `MNE`=1.

Comment: OK thanks for the comment. MNE is indeed part of a categorical variable with 3 levels ( 1=SME, 2=LARGE DOM and 3= MNE) which I changed to dummy variables with the command of i.categorie in state 12...
Can I estimate a total effect on the ETR for certain values of the other variables included in the interactions ( like in as the average value of FINAR= 0,2 and the average value of EQRATIO = 0,5 than the effect on the ETR of a MNE= .027-.064*0,5-.062*0,2 ) or is this just wrong? thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your follow-up question. The estimated effect of SME on ETR should be clear, since any interaction term that includes MNE or LARGE DOM will be equal to 0.  Please upvote or mark my solution as correct if it was helpful to you.

Comment: This is clear , the other dummys are indeed zero then. However, I'm interested in the (magnitude of the) difference between MNE and SME generally ( so taking into account all the interactions)...

Comment: The difference in expected value in `ETR` between levels of a binary variable `MNE` is defined by the first derivative of your equation, with respect to `MNE`.  The result of that should be what your looking for.  It takes into account the interaction effects that you are concerned about.  Hope this helps!

Comment: so the first derivative of MNE is this: .027-.064EQRATIO-.062FINAR. But what Can I say now of the effect of MNE compared with SME ( reference category) because the first derivate doesn't give me a number....

Comment: Yup, according to the function that you provided!

Comment: so the first derivative of MNE is this: .027-.064EQRATIO-.062FINAR. But what Can I say now of the effect of MNE compared with SME ( reference category) because the first derivate doesn't give me a number.... –

Comment: If you did not have interaction terms, you would simply be looking for the coefficient of `MNE`.  You cannot get a single number for the case you've presented, because the total estimated effect of `MNE`=1 is now dependent on the magnitude of `EQRATIO` and `FINAR`.